# How do I access a global model instance in laravel 4?

Tags: laravel-4

In Laravel 4, how do I create an instance of a model and make it globally available? Even in views. I'm looking to do something similar to the way you get the User instance using  Auth::User->name (the syntax I mean, not storing in a session) but in this case it would be ModelName::DefaultEntity->attribute.

A little more detail...

I am writing an application that will house multiple websites - a bit like a CMS. So I have a Website model. Each Website model will have a URL attribute so that when a user visits the URL the application can retrieve the Website model from the database and brand the website appropriately e.g. Title, logo, theme, etc...

I would like the current Website model to be available everywhere without having to create a new instance of Website in every controller/method. So in my layouts and views I could just say something like:

```
{{ Website::Website()->name }}
```

or

```
{{ CurrentWebsite::name }}
```

I have achieved the first one by making a static method in the Website model:

```
public static function current()
{
    return Website::find(1); // just to test it for now
}
```

But with that, it will have to do a database query every time I say:

```
{{ Website::current()->name }}
```

Plus it doesn't feel right.

Can anyone help?

Kind regards,

Robin

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything fancy here, and I'm a bit unclear of what you mean by 'globally' available.  Even with what you described, you should still be able to use Laravel as intended.  If you're worried about database calls, don't output the name of the current website using `Website::current()->name`, instead store the model to a variable first.  `$website = Website::current();`, then you can do `$website->name` and `$website->otherProperty` without a second database call.  For relationships, look into eager loading.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion. When I say globally I mean that I only want to create one instance that I can use in my routes, controllers, views etc and without having to manually pass the $website object in to every other class or view. I hope that makes sense. I think what I'm after is a facade but I don't know if that possible with an instance of a Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you already have is good, but if you just want prevent that query from executing every time, you can cache it:

```
public static function current()
{
    return Website::remember(10)->find(1); // just to test it for now
}
```

Adding a listener to your routes.php:

```
 DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time) { var_dump($sql); var_dump($bindings); });
```

And executing it:

```
{{ Website::current()->name }}
```

Will show the query in the first execution but not in the second, because it's cached.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are looking for 'a shared container bind'. See the [docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#basic-usage).

```
<?php
App::singleton('foo', function()
{
    return Website::whereCode('whoop')->first();
});

App::make('foo'); // every where you need it
```

Comment: Thank you, that is nearly it but I'd then want to just say foo::name inside a view or controller or route, without having to do the App::make('foo');

Maybe there isn't a way to do what I want then.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create normal class. Like CurrentWebsite or Website or whatever.

   ```
   class Website {
       public function a() {
         //your code
       }
    }
   ```
2. Create facade (WebsiteFacade.php)

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

   class WebsiteFacade extends Facade {

       protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'website'; }

   }
   ```
3. Create Service Provider

   ```
       use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

       class WebsiteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

       public function register()
       {
            $this->app->bind('website', function()
            {
                 return new Website();
             });
       }
       }
   ```

4.Go to your config/app.php and add folowing:

```
 'providers' => array(
      'WebsiteServiceProvider'
 )
```

and

```
 'aliases' => array(
      'WebsiteFacade'
 )
```

5.Refrech auto loader. And Now you can access Website class anywhere like this:

```
    Website::a();
```